# How to show the most right scroll view item which it's items are dynamic?

Tags: android, nativescript

i'm creating android app using Nativescript for right to left language(like persian or urdu).i have horizontal scrollview which items fill using repeater inside that. the repeater will get items data through webservice and then put it inside scroll view.

```
<ScrollView id="pishnehadScroll" orientation="horizontal" propertyChange="pchange">
                        <Repeater items="{{ products }} ">
                            <Repeater.itemsLayout>
                                <StackLayout orientation="horizontal"  horizontalAlignment="center">
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Repeater.itemsLayout>
                            <Repeater.itemTemplate>
                                <StackLayout class="pishnehad-items" horizontalAlignment="center">
                                    <Image src="{{ imagesrc }}" />
                                    <Label text="{{ productprice }}" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Repeater.itemTemplate>
                        </Repeater>
                    </ScrollView>
```

As i need to show scroll view items from right to left, i have to get scrollableWidth property of scrollView and use scrollToHorizontalOffset function.
The problem is scrollable width changes continuously as webservice result arrives.
How can i get final  scrollable width of scroll view and set scrollToHorizontalOffset function to show last item inside scroll view(the most right item)?

Comment: You can use RadListView, part of the nativescript-telerik-ui package, in place of the ScrollView. It allows you to set horizontal orientation to the listview, as well as to scroll to a specific index - http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/NativeScript/ListView/How-To/scroll-to-index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the comment of **pkanev** I would also recommend using ListView or RadListView preferable to Repeater when you are going to load more items (by more understand items that will not fit the screen). The reason is because RadListView (and ListView) both are using optimizations such as virtualization and recycling of cells, which are greatly improving performance. Using repeater with a large chunk of items will lead to OutOfMemory issues later...

Apart from that, you can access the properties of ScrollView called [scrollableWidth and scrollableHeight](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_scroll_view_.scrollview.html#scrollablewidth) once your web service has fetched all the data. As this is most likely an asynchronous operation, you can chain to it using then and call the scrollable width and height after the results from the fetching are received. You might need to 
e.g.

```
var scroll = <ScrollView>page.getViewById("pishnehadScroll");

setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(scroll.scrollableWidth);
}, 300);
```

Another approach using ListView with scrollToIndex and "cached' item index is used [here](https://github.com/NickIliev/NativeScript-Cosmos-Databank/blob/master/app/views/rovers/rover-photo-page.ts#L80-L88)